# Is "down to presentation" an idiom? And what does this line mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I just heard this line in a [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Boy_Girl_Thing).

> "So much of fine cuisine's down to presentation, don't you think, son?"

Context is father talks to son at a dining table at breakfast, as the mother fills their plates. What does the father mean?

The script can be found [here](https://subsaga.com/bbc/films/comedy/2009/its-a-boy-girl-thing/b017mr4x.html).

Comment: It means the food has to look good, before it even tastes good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What he says is that one of the most essential parts of fine cuisine is not only how the food tastes, but also the way it looks. In other words, the success of a dish also very much depends on how it's presented to the people who are going to eat it. This is one of the numerous variations on the ***[down to something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+to+something)*** idiom.

Example (not a perfect example, but it'll drive the point home):

> Everyone else on the team has failed. It's all down to me now to win the game.

So, whether we're going to win the game now depends solely on me. I'm the deciding factor now.

Comment: Good answer. I'll add that this idiom is often expressed as [_comes down to_](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+down+to), as in: _Everyone else on the team has failed; whether or not we win **comes** down to me._